# Error with Google Mock and shared_from_this?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, googlemock

I'm getting the following error thrown in a test of mine:

> unknown file: error: C++ exception with description
>   "tr1::bad_weak_ptr" thrown in the test body.

Stepping through the test one line at a time I can see the exception is being thrown on a line where I call:

```
MyClassSharedPointer myClassPointer(shared_from_this());
```

I need a pointer to the object the code is executing in, because I need to set the object up as an observer of one of it's members (using boost::signals to implement the observer).  The code appears to work fine while normally executing but from my test code I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that in my production code the myClass object is referenced as a shared_ptr whereas in my test code I had mistakenly declared the myClass object as a naked pointer.  Which explains why `shared_from_this()` wasn't working... because `this` wasn't actually a shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that myClass did not have a `shared_ptr` prior to `shared_from_this` being called (it was being used in a `unique_ptr`). And `shared_from_this` requires that at least one `shared_ptr` must already have been created. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27706002/3847255).