# std::bad_weak_ptr exception when using shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr

The following code causes a `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception when the ctor for `MyCommand` executes but not the function `MyCommand::execute`.

```
class Observer
{
public:
    Observer(){}
    virtual ~Observer(){}

    virtual void update(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

class Command
{
public:
    Command(){}
    virtual ~Command(){}

    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class MyCommand : public Command, public Observer, public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyCommand>
{
public:
    MyCommand()
    {
        // std::bad_weak_ptr exception
        std::shared_ptr<Observer> observer = shared_from_this();
    }

    virtual ~MyCommand(){}

private:
    virtual void execute()
    {
        // no exception
        std::shared_ptr<Observer> observer = shared_from_this();
    }
    virtual void update(const std::string& msg){}
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // causes std::bad_weak_ptr exception
    std::shared_ptr<Command> myCommand = std::make_shared<MyCommand>();

    // doesn't cause std::bad_weak_ptr exception
    myCommand->execute();
}
```

Reading up on `enable_shared_from_this`, I know that:

> Prior to calling shared_from_this on an object t, there must
>   be a std::shared_ptr that owns t.

I need to understand why the exception is thrown in the ctor but not in the `execute` function.

Is is something to do with the fact that the ctor has not fully executed before `shared_from_this` is called and therefore the object is not fully constructed?

If not, what is it?

Comment: How are you managing to get to the call function if the constrcutor throws?

Comment: @doctorlove I commented out the contents of the ctor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shared\_from\_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `shared_from_this` in constructor since no `shared_ptr` is assigned yet. See this [Why shared_from_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint)

However when the object is constructed and there is any `shared_ptr` associated with the instance, you are able to call `shared_from_this` as usual.

Answer (score 10):

Note: for me the issue was that I did not add the "public" keyword (hopefully this will save others some time).

E.g.:

```html
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> { //BAD
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> { //GOOD
```

Comment: Well, I met it too, what's the reason for it?

Comment: This may answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937112/stdenable-shared-from-this-public-vs-private