# Trivial cases of shared_ptr and weak_ptr failing

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, private-inheritance, enable-shared-from-this

I'm having trouble using `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` along with `enable_shared_from_this`.

When I google the symptoms of what I'm seeing, everybody suggests "you cannot use `shared_from_this()` when there are no `shared_ptr` instances owning your object.

But that's not my case.

Consider this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

class MyClass : std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>
{
public:
    void this_fails()
    {
        // Doesn't even assert(), because it throws bad_weak_ptr
        assert(shared_from_this());
    }
    void this_fails_too()
    {
        std::weak_ptr<MyClass> weak = weak_from_this();
        std::shared_ptr<MyClass> strong = weak.lock();
        // This assert fails
        assert(strong.get());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> obj = std::make_shared<MyClass>();

    obj->this_fails();
    obj->this_fails_too();
}
```

Both methods in `MyClass` crash the program. I must be missing something obvious - what is it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must inherit *publicly* from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Inheriting privately doesn't help - `std::shared_ptr` can't access the base class and set it up properly.

Comment: That must be the one of the most counter-intuitive behaviors I have seen. Why doesn't it cause compile time errors? -- Explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937112/stdenable-shared-from-this-public-vs-private

Comment: @LubosD I don't see why you would expect a compiler error. From the compilers point of view, inheriting privately is fine and calling `shared_from_this` is fine. That it doesn't give the desired run-time behaviour is not the compilers problem. The code is well formed C++ regardless of whether it gives you the expected behaviour or not.

Comment: @LubosD There is no easy way to give a compile error. The `std::shared_ptr` constructor has no mechanism to tell whether you made a mistake by privately inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this` or whether you just privately inherited from some class that publicly inherited from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. The `shared_from_this` function has no way of knowing the most derived class type so it also cannot detect the programmer's error.

Comment: Well, the standard could mandate checking for base with [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of), and then complaining if it is ambiguous or inaccessible.

Comment: @LubosD What's counter intuitive is that a class isn't required to derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this` but something will occur only if it does. This is very dirty and will not work if you allocate another class that uses membership instead of inheritance. Just have your own `weak_ptr` and maintain it yourself.

Comment: @Deduplicator But then you will have problems if you try to privately inherit from a class that has inherited from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Though, maybe this use case is rare enough to not matter.

Comment: @Brian That you will have anyway. Considering the private base depends on the Management being saved.

Answer (score 17):

You have to publicly inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` in order for it to work.