# shared_from_this and private inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) has this example of how to use `std::enable_shared_from_this` (slightly adjusted)

```
class Good : std::enable_shared_from_this<Good>
{
    public: std::shared_ptr<Good> getptr() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

...

auto good = std::make_shared<Good>();
good->getptr();
```

However, this does NOT work in Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise, Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2), i.e. a `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception is thrown.

Looking at other examples (including different ones from [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) or [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982991.aspx)) I noticed that they use `public` inheritance instead of `private` one. And using `public` inheritance actually solves my problem (no `std::bad_weak_ptr` anymore but a valid `shared_ptr` instead).

Cpp reference does not mention that I have to publicly inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, so where is the error? Is Visual Studio's behavior wrong (I guess there is a visibility problem when using `private` inheritance) or did cpp reference fail to mention this limitation?

PS: `make_shared<good>()` or `shared_ptr<Good>(new Good)` doesn't make a difference.

PSS: Both versions compile just fine, the private one just doesn't work, making this a quite nasty kind of bug.

EDIT: Changed `struct` to `class`. Cpp reference actually uses **public** inheritance in its examples. <s>Still, no word that it has to be public.</s> It is actually listed there, I just have to learn to read carefully. Thanks @Angew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared_from_this causing bad_weak_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697973/shared-from-this-causing-bad-weak-ptr)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that other question has a different root cause

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I wasn't sure, that's why I didn't hammer it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typical implementation of `std::enable_shared_from_this`, requires the `std::shared_ptr` constructor (called by `std::make_shared` in your case) to be able to detect the presence of a `std::enable_shared_from_this` base, so it can set the `std::weak_ptr` member of that base.

With private inheritance, that's not possible, so you get the runtime exception you got when calling `shared_from_this` (because the `std::weak_ptr` was never set, since the `std::shared_ptr` constructor couldn't detect the `std::enable_shared_from_this` base).

The C++ standard mentions such an implementation :

> *[ Note:* A possible implementation is shown below:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class enable_shared_from_this {
> private:
>   weak_ptr<T> __weak_this;
> protected:
>   constexpr enable_shared_from_this() : __weak_this() { }
>   enable_shared_from_this(enable_shared_from_this const &) { }
>   enable_shared_from_this& operator=(enable_shared_from_this const &) { return *this; }
>   ~enable_shared_from_this() { }
> public:
>   shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() { return shared_ptr<T>(__weak_this); }
>   shared_ptr<T const> shared_from_this() const { return shared_ptr<T const>(__weak_this); }
> };
> ```
>
> The `shared_ptr` constructors that create unique pointers can detect the presence of an `enable_shared_from_this` base and assign the newly created `shared_ptr` to its `__weak_this` member. *— end note ]*

The [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) you linked to also mentions this in the notes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. While I still think that this is a subtle source of errors, I guess it cannot be detected by static assertions of any kind.

Comment: @ArtificialMind : they could have added something like this in the `std::enable_shared_from_this` implementation : `static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*,enable_shared_from_this*>::value, "Needs public inheritance.");` (assuming the implementation mentioned above)

Comment: In principle it should possible to do this with private inheritance with a crapload of non-portable `friend` declarations

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question doesn't use private inheritance at all: `struct` defaults to public access control, both for members and for base classes.

Furthermore, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this&oldid=87273) does not omit anything. The text of the page clearly states:

> **Publicly** inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` ...

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for noticing! My production code uses a class, so it still failed there. At least cpp reference is consistent.